# Javascript functions not returning desired result

Tags: javascript, ajax, undefined

I have a function that contains a switch statement to return a string based on an inputted integer. I've shortened it for brevity. The cases past `1` doesn't matter, as the case integer just increments and returns different string values. The setup is the same.

`function idToGame(id) { switch (id) { case 1: return 'loz';break; } }`

Whenever I test it using my Google Chrome console, it works fine.

`idToGame(1)` returns *loz*

So let's use the variable `game` as an example. Below, we are assuming the value for 'pm_game' is 1.

`var game = document.getElementById('pm_game').value;`

Therefore, `game` is set to *1*.

Here's the weird part. Whenever I try to use this: (*note: the value below is 1*)

`var game = idToGame(document.getElementById('pm_game').value);`

It sets `game` to *undefined*.

Am I missing something? Why does it become *undefined* when it's really supposed to be *loz*?

Comment: could you add the html element #pm_game to your question so we can see what does the value attribute should be?

Comment: You need to post your code. I'm guessing your assumption that document.getElementById('pm_game').value is 1 is not correct. What kind of element is it? And how is its value set?

Comment: @kumiau It's a `<select>` tag, in this example, I have the first option selected, which has a value of 1.

@Jodes the assumption is correct. I've used the console to return `document.getElementById('pm_game').value` and it returns 1. But when it gets plugged into the variable with the function, it returns undefined.

Comment: Here is a link to my Google Chrome console log: http://pastebin.com/zqWuGX4J

Comment: Don't forget to vote if your problem is resolved. Everyone is actually fighting to get it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the value of any input field, like this:

```
var game = document.getElementById('pm_game').value;
```

returned result is always a string, not a number like you expect. So in order to make it work you need to cast a string to a number. For example using `parseInt`:

```
var game = parseInt(document.getElementById('pm_game').value, 10);
// or game = + document.getElementById('pm_game').value;
// or game = Number(document.getElementById('pm_game').value);
```

Or move `parseInt` conversion into `id2game` function before switch.

Comment: +1 for using a [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) in your answer and mentioning the [Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29)

Comment: Thank you and all who answered similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Switches in javascript use strict type checking (`===`), so, `1` (Number) is considered not equal to `'1'` (String). Two options :

- Try `switch(parseInt(id))` to perform conversion from string to integer.
- If you don't want to perform conversion, simply add quotes around each case values as follows : `case '1'`.

Additionaly, for debugging purpose, you can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to print the type in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Switch uses the === operator. Where 1 is not equal '1'.

Just tried in the console you need to tryparse it. Below is an example.

```
var f = function(id) { 
   switch (parseInt(id)) 
   { 
      case 1: 
         return 'loz';
         break; 
   } 
}
```

with the old function: f(1) would return 'loz', but f('1') didn't.

I would prefer comparing to '1' instead of 1 - to avoid the parse. but I am not sure if this i what you want:

```
var f = function(id) { 
   switch (id) 
   { 
      case '1': 
         return 'loz';
         break; 
   } 
}
```